# Passing int ** to pthread_create in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to build a basic "game" server in C, I stock each file descriptor of an accepted socket in an `int *`, each of these are stocked in `int ** clients`. I then create a thread and pass `clients` as its argument.

Here's the code:

`game_server_threaded.c`

```
#define PLAYERS 4
int ** clients;
/* Setting up server... */
    clients = malloc(sizeof(int *) * PLAYERS);

    while (1)
    {   
        for (int i = 0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
            clients[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
            *clients[i] = accept(server_sock, 
                (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &size);
            printf("s%d: %d\n", i, *clients[i]);
        }

        pthread_t th;
        if (pthread_create(&th, NULL, play_game, clients) < 0)
            die("create thread");
    }
```

`void * play_game(void * s)`

```
void * play_game(void * s)
{
    int ** clients = (int **) s;

    srand (time(NULL));
    int k = rand() % MAX_K;
    int tries = 3;
    int turn = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < PLAYERS; i++)
    {
        printf("s%d: %d\n", i, *clients[i]);
    }

    /* Game mechanics... */
}
```

However, the output is very weird. In the thread, all `*clients[i]` are set, except for `*clients[0]`.

Here it is:

```
s0: 4
s1: 5
s2: 6
s3: 7

s0: 0
s1: 5
s2: 6
s3: 7
```

I've tested this extensively with different casts and such. I've also created a version which sends this struct to the thread:

```
struct player_threads {
    char * msg;
    char c;
    int ** clients;
};
```

In the thread, `msg` and `c` are intact but the first element of clients is still 0!

I managed to get it working with a simple `int * clients`, but still, I can't comprehend this behaviour, could someone explain it to me?

Thank you.

EDIT****

The file from which the above code comes from is relatively short, it can be found here if you want to reproduce it.

https://pastebin.com/61nRKvQf

Comment: Most likely, you are doing something which produces undefined behaviour. Show an entire [mre].

Comment: Your code [doesn't demonstrate the problem](https://godbolt.org/z/v56brs7Yb), which is probably caused by out of bounds writes. `-fsanitize=address` is great at finding these problems.

Comment: Shouldn't `clients = malloc(sizeof(int *) * PLAYERS);` be inside the `while (1)` loop?

Comment: Why do you need `int **clients` rather than the simpler `int *clients`?

Comment: @IanAbbott That fixed it, thank you. Could you elaborate on why this causes systematic undefined behaviour when it's passed to pthread_create()?

Comment: @rici I've added the full code to a pastebin if you want to reproduce it, it's relatively short.

Comment: @ikegami Interesting compiler options, I'll be adding them to my arsenal. Thank you.

Comment: @IanAbbott  It may not apply to the current implementation, but it's good practice as it avoids an accept overwriting a file descriptor being used by another thread (i.e. a new client connects and the accept call is executed before the thread was able to store the file descriptor concerning its communication).

Comment: What is it that you need inside the thread function? Let's assume it is the type `T`. Then, you allocate one (note that it must outlive the use inside the thread function) and pass a `T*` to the thread. The `void*` you receive there is then the `T*` you provided and you convert it back. The only mistake in all those conversions is that you take one address too much or too little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The created threads are sharing data that they expected to remain stable but is actually being modified outside the thread.

Specifically, the memory pointed to by `clients`, pointing to an "array" of `int *` is allocated before any threads are created. It is being filled in with a new set of `int *` before each new thread is created and is then passed to the new thread in the final argument of the `pthread_create` call.  When the new thread examines the "array" of `int *`, it may see a mixture of the original elements at the time of the `pthread_create` call plus some elements that have since been overwritten by the main thread. Also, because assignment to an object of pointer type is not guaranteed to be atomic, it is also possible for the thread to access a partially updated (and therefore invalid) pointer value.

In the example given, the first four lines are printed by the main thread by this code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
            clients[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
            *clients[i] = accept(server_sock, 
                (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &size);
            printf("s%d: %d\n", i, *clients[i]);
        }
```

Output:

```
s0: 4
s1: 5
s2: 6
s3: 7
```

The main thread then creates a new thread:

```
        pthread_t th;
        if (pthread_create(&th, NULL, play_game, clients) < 0)
            die("create thread");
```

The main thread then repeats the above `for` loop. The first thing that does is overwrite `clients[0]` with a new pointer value from `malloc(sizeof(int))` and then it blocks on the `accept` call.

Meanwhile, the thread starts and prints stuff from the `clients` array, but `clients[0]` may have already been overwritten.

Output:

(At this point, the main thread has overwritten `client[0]`. The contents of `client[0][0]` are indeterminate at this point, but happens to contain 0 here.) ...

```
s0: 0
```

(At this point, the main thread is blocked on the call to `accept`, so `clients[1]` through to `clients[3]` still have the same values they had at the time of the call to `pcreate_thread`.) ...

```
s1: 5
s2: 6
s3: 7
```

---

To correct the problem, a new `clients` block needs to be allocated for each thread. That can be done by moving the allocation of `clients` into the loop that creates the new threads:

```
#define PLAYERS 4
int ** clients;
/* Setting up server... */

    while (1)
    {   
        clients = malloc(sizeof(int *) * PLAYERS);
        for (int i = 0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
            clients[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
            *clients[i] = accept(server_sock, 
                (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &size);
            printf("s%d: %d\n", i, *clients[i]);
        }

        pthread_t th;
        if (pthread_create(&th, NULL, play_game, clients) < 0)
            die("create thread");
    }
```

---

As an aside, there is unnecessary indirection in the use of `int **clients` since all that is really being passed in this example is one `int` value per player (containing the file descriptor of the accepted socket connection for that player). That could be simplified as follows:

**Main thread**

```
#define PLAYERS 4
int * clients;
/* Setting up server... */

    while (1)
    {
        clients = malloc(sizeof(int) * PLAYERS);
        for (int i = 0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
            clients[i] = accept(server_sock, 
                (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &size);
            printf("s%d: %d\n", i, clients[i]);
        }

        pthread_t th;
        if (pthread_create(&th, NULL, play_game, clients) < 0)
            die("create thread");
    }
```

**Game thread**

```
void * play_game(void * s)
{
    int * clients = s;

    srand (time(NULL));
    int k = rand() % MAX_K;
    int tries = 3;
    int turn = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < PLAYERS; i++)
    {
        printf("s%d: %d\n", i, clients[i]);
    }

    /* Game mechanics... */
}
```

---

For the version that passes a pointer to a `struct player_threads` to each thread, with the `clients` member type simplified to `int *`:

**`struct player_threads`**

```
struct player_threads {
    char * msg;
    char c;
    int * clients;
};
```

**Main thread**

```
#define PLAYERS 4
struct player_threads * players;
/* Setting up server... */

    while (1)
    {
        players = malloc(sizeof(*players));
        players->clients = malloc(sizeof(int) * PLAYERS);
        players->msg = "Hello";
        players->c = 'X';
        for (int i = 0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
            players->clients[i] = accept(server_sock, 
                (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &size);
            printf("s%d: %d\n", i, players->clients[i]);
        }

        pthread_t th;
        if (pthread_create(&th, NULL, play_game, players) < 0)
            die("create thread");
    }
```

**Game thread**

```
void * play_game(void * s)
{
    struct player_threads * players = s;

    srand (time(NULL));
    int k = rand() % MAX_K;
    int tries = 3;
    int turn = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < PLAYERS; i++)
    {
        printf("s%d: %d\n", i, players->clients[i]);
    }

    /* Game mechanics... */
}
```

---

As another aside, it would be better to replace the calls to `srand` and `rand` with a call to `rand_r` because the `rand` call might not be thread-safe:

```
    unsigned int seed = time(NULL);
    int k = rand_r(&seed) % MAX_K;
```

`seed` needs to be in storage local to the thread. In the above, it is on the thread's stack, but it may be better to provide storage for it as a member of `struct player_threads`:

```
struct player_threads {
    char * msg;
    char c;
    unsigned int seed;
    int * clients;
};
```

```
    players->seed = time(NULL);
    int k = rand_r(&players->seed) % MAX_K;
```